# What material is Embo's hat made out of?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Is it known what material Embo's hat is made of?

Comment: I can't find any canon reference to the material used. If you put a gun to my head, I'd say [cortosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis) but that would be a pure guess.

Comment: I was about to say same thing, I even voted your comment than I remembered that I never saw Embo deflecting and lightsaber attacks. I'm not saying it can't I'm just saying it was never shown. So it doesn't have to necessarily be made by Cortosis. There is mentioning that some blasters cant penetrate Stormtrooper armor so it is possible that Embo's hat was made from same metal as Stormtrooper armor

Answer (score 5):

### We don't know.

According to the *Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary* entry for another member of the [Kyuzo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyuzo) species, [Zuvio](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zuvio), it's a "[Kyuzo war helmet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyuzo_war_shield)," known also as a "Kyuzo war shield." Not much else is currently known about it other than what we see on-screen.

[image]

It's important to note that while Embo's helmet is [fully blaster-proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYcYDHB91cc), there is nothing to suggest that it's lightsaber-proof, so there is no particular reason to believe it's cortosis.